# ¿Cómo cerrar modal en boostrap 5 sin apretar un botón? Boostrap 5/ Vue 3

Tags: javascript, bootstrap, vue.js, modal, popup

El modal está levantado y cuando me llega un evento que confirma la finalización de un contador lo que quiero hacer es cerrarlo automáticamente sin necesidad de hacer click en el botón para cerrarlo.
Probé creando una nueva instancia del modal y ejecutando la función hide() pero no funciona.

```
finalizaContador() {
      //Evento que confirma la finalización del contador.
      console.log("Terminó el contador");
      this.startCounter = false;
      var myModal = new bootstrap.Modal(
        document.getElementById("recoordinate-appointment") //ID del modal.
      );
      //Ocultar modal
      myModal.hide();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No me funcionaba la función hide() por una configuración diferente de boostrap en mi proyecto, finalmente lo resolví forzando el click cuando me llega el evento.

Answer (score 0):

si usas Boostrap-Vue:

```
<b-modal id="modal-1" ref="settingsModalUpdatePass">
  //Contenido
</b-modal>
```

si lo quieres ocultar seria algo asi:

```
this.$refs['settingsModalUpdatePass'].hide()
```

Esta informacion se encuentra en :
[Boostrap-vue.Doc](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/modal)